# Why is 'this.props.children' null to use for the react-router (React-Redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, reactjs

In my root component, I have the following react-router set up:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={HomePage}
          path="/"
        />
        <Route
          component={FirstPage}
          path="page1"
        />
        <Route
          component={SecondPage}
          path="page2"
        />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Then in my 'HomePage.js', the following allows to go to the 'FirstPage' if clicked on:

```
<RaisedButton
  containerElement={<Link to={`FirstPage`}/>}
  label="Sign In"
  labelColor='#88898C'
  labelStyle={{textTransform:'intial'}}
  style={styles.signIn}
/>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(HomePage)
```

And in my smart component 'FirstPage.js', in render just have:

```
{this.props.children}
```

then:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FirstPage)
```

To render a component on based on the `<Link/>` clicked on with the proper route, but it shows that `{this.props.children}` is 'null'. So for example, if  with `path2` is called on, the `{SecondPage}` is rendered in place of {this.props.children} in `FirstPage.js`.

Just defining `{this.props.children}` alone worked fine before I added `HomePage.js`. Now after I added it, it says `{this.props.children}` is 'null'. What may be the issue? Any guidance or insight would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to have nested routes in order to render its child components (this.props.children)

Answer (score 3):

It's null because it has no children.

You should have a 'smart component' or 'container' specified in your parent `<Route>`.

e.g. You would use props.children if you had a structure like this:

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
  //...
</Route>
```

In this case, your App component will have {this.props.children} in it's render() method.